# JWT Authentication / Authorization with Angular and MVC Core

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, openiddict

I'm working on an Angular SPA using ASP.NET MVC core as the backend API and i'm 
having a lot of trouble getting my JWT authentication to work correctly.

I am using Openiddict as my JWT Middleware to issue tokens.  I can successfully send a token request to my controller, log the user in, and send the token back to the client.

However when I try to access the protected API route I get a 401 unauthorized message. I can see that the token is being sent in the header of the request so it must not be getting read properly on the server side so I think it is just a configuration issue.  Every resource I've looked at for this makes it seem like there isn't anything else configuration wise to do.

Here are the relevant parts of code:

**Startup Configure Services**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DbContext>();

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config =>
       {
           config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
           config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
       })
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddOpenIddict<DbContext>()
            .AddMvcBinders()
            .EnableTokenEndpoint("/auth/token")
            .UseJsonWebTokens()
            .AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
            //.AddSigningCertificate()
            .DisableHttpsRequirement();

        services.AddLogging();
    }
```

**Startup Configure App**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, RequestJockeyDataSeeder seeder, ILoggerFactory factory)
    {

        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions()
        {
            DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" }
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseOpenIddict();

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Audience = "http://localhost:5000",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        });

        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

**Controller** - I got this from an example on the web

```
[HttpPost("~/auth/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        if (!request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            // Return bad request if the request is not for password grant type
            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                ErrorDescription = "The specified grant type is not supported."
            });
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Return bad request if the user doesn't exist
            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                ErrorDescription = "Invalid username or password"
            });
        }

        // Check that the user can sign in and is not locked out.
        // If two-factor authentication is supported, it would also be appropriate to check that 2FA is enabled for the user
        if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user) || (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user)))
        {
            // Return bad request is the user can't sign in
            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                ErrorDescription = "The specified user cannot sign in."
            });
        }

        if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
        {
            // Return bad request if the password is invalid
            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                ErrorDescription = "Invalid username or password"
            });
        }

        // The user is now validated, so reset lockout counts, if necessary
        if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
        {
            await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
        }

        // Create the principal
        var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

        // Claims will not be associated with specific destinations by default, so we must indicate whether they should
        // be included or not in access and identity tokens.
        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            // For this sample, just include all claims in all token types.
            // In reality, claims' destinations would probably differ by token type and depending on the scopes requested.
            claim.SetDestinations(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken, OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
        }

        // Create a new authentication ticket for the user's principal
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            principal,
            new AuthenticationProperties(),
            OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // Include resources and scopes, as appropriate
        var scope = new[]
        {
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
    OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
}.Intersect(request.GetScopes());

        ticket.SetResources("http://localhost:5000/");
        ticket.SetScopes(scope);
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15);

        // Sign in the user
        return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

I'll leave out the angular http interceptor because the route fails through both the application as well as through Postman.  Is there anything I'm missing as far as configuring MVC to handle these tokens properly?

Answer (score -1):

Ended up solving this issue after enabling logging and seeing more detailed errors.

I updated my JwtBearerAuthentication to this:

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Audience = "http://localhost:5000/",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
            }
         }
```

The main change being the `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = False`

Comment: Outch no, don't do that: disabling signing key would allow anybody to create counterfeit tokens. Please update your question with your logs, it will be easier to help you.